# Transitioning from SQL-based data retrieval to Web Services

Tags: sql, web-services

My customer is moving from providing data directly through SQL access to exposing the same data through a web service that will expose the same DB, but due to political reasons they're cutting the direct DB access. They're using SOAP for the web service but that's irrelevant to the issue. They come to me with requests that are vague in a sense that they don't know where the answer to their question is, so I'm left with no other options than to go poking around their data to see from where I could possibly find the correct data for their needs.

With SQL it's been more or less painless, write a simple query with a join or three and Bob's your uncle. In the worst case I have needed to select one row from the tables to see what they contain but that's not part of the actual data retrieval.

Now, with web services, I'm struggling to achieve the same. I feel like I have no tools to efficiently explore the data in a flexible way and each join from SQL requires a new query that includes manually merging results from the previous ones. A good example is

> Show me all the users that are part of a service where the name begins with "FOO"

With SQL I would do a simple

```
SELECT
  users.first_name,
  users.last_name,
  services.name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN services ON (users.service_id=services.id)
WHERE services.name LIKE 'FOO%'
```

With the SOAP API I'm forced to do a search for the services, write down the IDs and then do a search for the users. They keyword here is efficiency, I can get the same results but it takes so much more time that for anything more complex we might talk about hours instead of minutes.

The question is two-fold:

1. Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same?
2. Are there tools that would ease the pain, even if it means the join equivalents would need manual configuration to make work but would then work transparently once configured?

So far I've been using SOAP-UI (and Postman when applicable) for exploring the data. With Postman the scripting helps a bit so I can save the intermediate result into a variable and use them on the subsequent calls. I feel like I'm left with no other options than to take a simple(ish) way of programmatically accessing the API and scripting the same searches. Java is the weapon of choice at the customer for multiple reasons but that isn't the simplest way, so I'm also looking for recommendations regardless of the language.

Comment: The web service idea simply doesn't suit the requirement - data discovery. Unless you build a web service which lets you submit a query. Which is a good way to solve your issue and make it clear to the parties requiring a web service API that they don't know what they're talking about. What you say is correct - creating a web service per table for example will cause the database to do a ridiculous amount of additional work that SQL achieves most efficiently.

Comment: To put it another way, a web API needs an API definition and a custom SQL query doesn't. So the API could be "this API accepts any SQL and returns the result" or it could be "we have one method per table" or it could be "we have one method per stored procedure"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for the input, it's relieving to know I'm not totally lost. The reason they're dropping SQL connections is that we use that for pulling data from a system to another, so making that through the API is no problem, it's only a problem for the "figure out what's needed" part, so I think I'll ask to have a personal account for the DB for audit reasons and have the actual work done through the API.

Comment: That makes more sense. The correct API for the correct purpose. Even then, web API's are not particularly ideal for back end data integration. If you're going DB to DB, putting a web API in the middle just makes it complicated but so be it

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Make your comments as as an answer and I'll happily accept it :)

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather not as they are opinion based and didn't actually answer your question.... naturally I think my opinion is 100% correct.